# There was a problem building a simple server with fastapi using Gunicorn (feat. worker)

Tags: python, mariadb, gunicorn, fastapi

I did a simple backend test with fastapi

put data in docs using post and i readed data use get

However, there are times when data comes out and times when it is not updated, every time you press F5,

My code is very simple, and I'll show the code

What's the problem? and how do solve it?

db_class.py

```html
from sqlalchemy import Column, TEXT, INT, BIGINT
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(BIGINT,nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    number = Column(INT, nullable=False)
```

db_conn.py

```html
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

conn_string = "mysql+pymysql://root:password@mariadb:3306/example"

class engineconn:

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string, pool_recycle =500)

    def sessionmaker(self):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        return session

    def connection(self):
        conn = self.engine.connect()
        return conn
```

main.py

```html
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from db_conn import engineconn
from db_class import Test

app = FastAPI()

engine = engineconn()
session = engine.sessionmaker()


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    number: int


@app.get("/")
async def first_get():
    example = session.query(Test).all()
    return example


@app.post("/post")
async def first_post(item: Item):
    addMemo = Test(name=item.name, number=item.number)
    session.add(addMemo)
    session.commit()
    return item
```

Dockerfile

```html
FROM python:3.9.0

WORKDIR /home/

RUN echo '2323'

RUN git clone (my git)

WORKDIR /home/(my_folder)

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["bash", "-c", "gunicorn main:app --worker-class=uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers=3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```html
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.5
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - /home/fastapi_chk/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
  fastapi_test:
    image: fastapi_test
    networks:
      - network
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - mariadb-database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rkwkrh13!#
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

networks:
  network:

volumes:
  mariadb-database:
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the database session every request, maybe it gets exhausted? Is there an error when you do not get data from your endpoint?

You probably should think about putting your `Session` in a dependency that is closed after each request. Like so:

db_conn.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

conn_string = "mysql+pymysql://root:password@mariadb:3306/example"

class engineconn:

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string, pool_recycle =500)

    def sessionmaker(self):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        # we want this to be a callable, see main.py
        return Session
        

    def connection(self):
        conn = self.engine.connect()
        return conn
```

main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from db_conn import engineconn
from db_class import Test

app = FastAPI()

engine = engineconn()
Session = engine.sessionmaker()

def get_db():
    db = Session()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    number: int


@app.get("/")
async def first_get(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    example = db.query(Test).all()
    return example


@app.post("/post")
async def first_post(item: Item, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    addMemo = Test(name=item.name, number=item.number)
    db.add(addMemo)
    db.commit()
    return item
```

This way, your session is not constantly reused by your application.